# How could I send out a mail with Email template but only provide email address as a string

Tags: email

How could I send out email without using standard object id but use "EMAIL" string instead?

```
    public void doSendMail(Id emailTemplateId, String restoreUrl, Id contactId){
        EmailTemplate emailTemplate = 
            [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body 
              from EmailTemplate where Id = :emailTemplateId LIMIT 1]; // or 
        //build the email message
        Messaging.Singleemailmessage email = new Messaging.Singleemailmessage();
        email.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);

        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailmessage[] {email});

    }
```

Comment: [Outbound Email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
email.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
```

you can use this [SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) method (that accepts an array argument):

```
String emailAddress = 'abc@def.com';
email.setToAddresses(new String[]{emailAddress});
```